# Import other Spring Boot application without it's beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to use some classes that exist inside another spring boot application. How can I import them whitout loading all it's beans in my application.

Answer (score 1):

The `@ComponentScan` annotation is responsible for automatically loading any classes marked with `@Component` or its derived annotations. This annotation has various options to filter which beans are loaded.

If the parent package of the imported application is different from that of your main application, you can simply set the `basePackages` option to a specific parent package.

For example, say that your main application has the package `com.example.main` and the imported application has `com.example.imported`, you can put in:

```java
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.main"})
```

This will import only beans defined under the main application package.

If this is not enough, you can also use the `excludeFilters` option on the same annotation.

```java
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters={
  @ComponentScan.Filter(type=FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, value=Imported.class)
})
```

You can also combine both options for more specific filtering.

Answer (score 0):

@metacubed answer is probably sufficient. But another very simple approach would be to use `@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {BeansToExport.class, MoreBeansToExport.class, ...})` - Example:

```
@Configuration
public class BeansToExport {

   @Bean
   public ServiceClass serviceClassBean(){
      return new ServiceClass();
   }

   @Bean
   public RespositoryClass repositoryClassBean(){
      return new RepositoryClass();
   }

}
```

I would call this an inclusive strategy, whereas @metacube's example would be an exclusive strategy. Both have their uses.